# Is it possible to use dask imperative to build function graphs and then supply inputs later?

Tags: python, dask

We're looking at using dask, in particular its lazy compute and dag capabilities.

We have a moderately complicated compute dag, *with unknown inputs*. We want to be able to build it ahead of time, and then use it on different inputs.

I think we can do this with the dict / tuple interface:

```
from dask.threaded import get
import pandas as pd
power = lambda x, y: x**y

dsk = {'x': pd.Series(pd.np.random.rand(20)),
       'y': 2,
       'z': (power, 'x', 'y'),
       'w': (sum, ['x', 'y', 'z'])}
```

Then we have `dsk` as the portable dag, and can replace `x` with whatever we want. (indeed, we didn't need to include it above initially).

```
dsk['x'] = pd.Series(pd.np.random.rand(20))
get(dsk, 'w')
```

But can we do this with `dask.imperative`? My initial results suggest that we can't get to `x`:

```
x=pd.Series()

def filter_below_3(ds):
    return ds[ds<3]

f=do(filter_below_3)
graph=f(x)

graph.dask
# {'filter_below_3-0ae5a18c-206d-4293-84b6-eb0d39243296': (<function __main__.filter_below_3>,  [])}
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

dask.do and dask.value were both renamed to dask.delayed a long while ago.  See the [changelog](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/docs/source/changelog.rst#090--2016-05-11) for more information.

#### Original Answer

Currently there is no standard way to swap out leaf values within dask.imperative.  However, there are a couple of decent options.

#### Switch to dict/tuple interface

Dask.imperative just builds a dict for you.  You can swap out values after you construct the dictionary.

```
from operator import add, mul
from dask import do, value
from dask.threaded import get

input = value('dummy-value', name='my-special-input')
x = do(add)(input, 1)
y = do(mul)(x, x)
dsk = y.dask

>>> dsk['my-special-input'] = 10
>>> get(dsk, y.key)
121
```

#### Use functions

All dask imperative graphs should be fairly cheap to construct.  You could create a function to produce your graph for each input

```
def f(input):
    x = do(add)(input, 1)
    y = do(mul)(x, x)
    return y

>>> f(10).compute()
121
```

Comment: This example did not work for me. Specifically, "from dask import do, value" does not work. I installed dask by downloading the zip from github yesterday and doing "python setup.py install".

Comment: I've added an edit stating that these were renamed to dask.delayed

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Matt! Looks like things are will work now.